# kdb: splayed table sym file not loaded

Tags: kdb

I'm following [14.2.4 Basic Operations on Splayed Tables](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#1424-basic-operations-on-splayed-tables) on kx.com.

In an empty directory, running below

```
`:db/t/ set .Q.en[`:db;] ([] s1:`a`b`c; v:10 20 30; s2:`x`y`z)
```

created a splayed table successfully:

```
[22:52:57] [~/tmp] tree
.
└── db
    ├── sym
    └── t
        ├── s1
        ├── s2
        └── v
```

Q1) After loading the table using `$ q db/t` as instructed, the enumerated symbols did not get displayed. What am I missing here?

```
[22:54:24] [~/tmp] q db/t
KDB+ 4.0 ...

q)select from t
s1 v  s2
--------
0  10 3
1  20 4 
2  30 5
```

Q2) Loading using `$ q db` worked: the symfile was loaded successfully, and symbols appeared correctly. However, is there a way to load only one table? (Here, if I had more tables, all of them would've been loaded)

```
[23:05:18] [~/tmp] Q db
KDB+ 4.0 ...

q)t
s1 v  s2
--------
a  10 x 
b  20 y 
c  30 z 
q)sym
`a`b`c`x`y`z
```

Comment: What's wrong with loading all tables? Splayed/partitioned tables are memory-mapped and not loaded fully into memory so it costs almost nothing to load the db (which is the more common practice).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Agreed loading entire db is the way to go. I asked the question mainly because section 14.2.4 in Q for Mortals had an example where it (a) first creates a splayed table, then (b) runs `$q /db/t` which loads that table only (hence missing out on loading the sym file). -- I was mostly wondering if there's a specific reason in that example to load only the table t, and not `$q /db` as you and others pointed out.

Comment: You're not wrong to find it strange - in my opinion that's a bad piece of documentation and is never used in practice! More confusing than it's worth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1 - When loading just the table using `q db/t` only the contents of that subdirectory are loaded. The sym file is not loaded as it is not located in the `db/t` subdirectory, which is why you don't see the enumerated symbols displayed. Best practice is to load the entire database using `q db` or `\l db` in your q session.

Q2 - If not using `q db` to load the entire database directory then `get` can be used as seen in the other answer to load both the table and sym file. The function `loadTable` below can handle loading both the table and sym file when passed the path to the table, as long as both exist in the same directory.

```
q)loadTable:{p:` vs x;`sym set get .Q.dd[p 0;`sym];p[1]set get x}
q)loadTable`:db/t
`t
q)t
s1 v  s2
--------
a  10 x
b  20 y
c  30 z
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `get` https://code.kx.com/q/ref/get/#get

```
q)sym:get `:db/sym
q)t:get `:db/t/
```